# Single word(s) that describes all activity sorted by recency

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, software

We are struggling to find the correct word(s) that describes a list of all messages in the system that are sorted by recency.

`Trending` does not work because what we are displaying is not what is popular in the system, only the most recent.

`Recent` does not work because it implies there is a limit to the number of messages we display.

`All` does not work because it does not imply that they are sorted by recency.

Any hints or suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Youngest first.

Comment: You could say it's a [LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) (Last In First Out) list, or that the items are displayed in [reverse chronological sequence](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22reverse+chronological+sequence%22) (newest first, where "chronological sequence" normally starts with the *first, oldest* thing).

Comment: Here on SE, we use *Newest* and [most recently] *Active*.

Comment: "Date/time order"

Answer (score 5):

You could use **chronological** / **reverse-chronological**, though that's really two words.

> adjective: chronological
>
> (of a record of events) starting with the earliest and following the
>   order in which they occurred.
>       *"The messages are sorted in a reverse-chronological order"*

Source: google keyword search

Answer (score 4):

This is usually either referred to as

**Latest** ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latest))

> most recent
>
> *The **latest** news on this story*

or

**Newest** ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/newest))

> of recent origin, production, purchase, etc.; having but lately come or been brought into being
>
> *The **newest** item on the list*

---

If the user is able to reverse the order (say, by clicking) the antonyms to each, respectively, would be

**Earliest** ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/earliest))

> near the beginning of a period of time
>
> *The **earliest** known hominid fossil on record*

or

**Oldest** ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oldest))

> of, relating to, or originating in a past era
>
> *The **oldest** electronic transmission dates back to...*"